# Ellipsize in textView - dots are aligned to center of textView height

Tags: android

I'v added ellipsize to my textView, but the dots at the end are higher, than the rest of text. Check the picture:

[image: Ellipsize view]

How to move dots from the end to the bottom of text?

Edit: Below is TextView container code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/vToolbarAttachedLeftLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vToolbarFirstHorizontalGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vToolbarStartVerticalGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vToolbarSecondHorizontalGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vToolbarAttachedRightLayout"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables"/>
```

Below I added TextView creation code:

```
val titleTextView = TextView(context)
    val titleLayoutParams = ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
    titleLayoutParams.setMargins(context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_medium), 0, 0, 0)
    titleTextView.layoutParams = titleLayoutParams
    titleTextView.setTextAppearance(R.style.ToolbarTextViewAppearance)
    titleTextView.tag = ToolbarView.TITLE_TAG
```

Then I set additional data:

```
(titleView as TextView?)?.let {
        it.text = title
        it.ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.END
        it.maxLines = 1
    }
```

TextView style:

```
<style name="ToolbarTextViewAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_large</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/noto_sans_bold</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code that use TextView for it.

Comment: Also, are you using a custom font? What does look like if you `setText("\u2026")`? Is that raised, too?

Comment: @MikeM. You are right. I'm setting custom font. When I deleted fontFamily attribute from style that I use, the problem disappeared. Is there a way to keep fontFamily attribute and make ellipsize work?

Comment: Well, you'd probably have to do it manually. I'm assuming that the ellipsis character – the `\u2026` I mentioned above – is just like that in your font. If its period character – `.` – is on the baseline, then you could simply replace it with 3 periods, but you might have to remove another character or 2 from the ellipsized string, since you're replacing 1 character with 3. Alternatively, you could try wrapping the ellipsis character in a [`SubscriptSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SubscriptSpan), which should shift it downward about the right distance.